# how to pass objects selected in check box from jsp to servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I am passing list of objects from servlet to JSP. Showing them on JSP page like

```
<c:forEach items="${plcContacts}" var="contact">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" class="case" id ="${contact.col2}" >></input><br></td>
    <td>${contact.col5}</td>
    <td>${contact.col4}</td>
    <td class="teamFunction">${contact.col2}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

In the above,

```
contact.col5 is email id, 
contact.col4 is name,
contact.col2 is team member function.
```

So I have buttons for selecting all contacts , deselect all contacts, contacts based on their function. I have done it using JQuery successfully as below.

```
 // add multiple select functionality
    $("#CheckAll").click(function () {
          $('.case').prop('checked', true);
    });

    $("#UnCheckAll").click(function () {
          $('.case').prop('checked', false);
    });

// check by Function
    $("#CheckByFunction").click(function() {    
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            var plc = $('#plcFunction').val().replace(/ /g, '-');
            var teamFunction =  this.id.replace(/ /g, '-');
            if (plc == teamFunction) {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                 $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
```

My question here is when next button is clicked on this JSP page , I need to send the list of contact objects whose check boxes were selected to servlet. I am trying to do like below.

```
**//read all the checked contacts**
$("#Next").click(function() {
  selected = new Array();
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() { 
    selected.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

I can retrieve all contact objects in servlet by putting them in session , but I need only the contacts with check box selected. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your checkboxes an unique value identifying the checked value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="${contact.col2}" />
```

Then you can just use [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) to obtain all checked values:

```
String[] checkedContacts = request.getParameterValues("contacts");
```

That's all. No need to collect it into some JS array on submit. That's an ugly JS hack which doesn't degrade gracefully (i.e. if enduser has JS disabled, the whole submit breaks).

Answer (score 0):

First, your html needs a value attribute set, not an id:

```
<c:forEach items="${plcContacts}" var="contact">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" class="case" value="${contact.col2}"></input></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Second, your javascript should be something along the lins of:

```
$("#CheckAll").click(function () {
    //Notice use of attr here, not prop
    $('.case').attr('checked', true);
});

$("#UnCheckAll").click(function () {
      //notice we are remove attr
      $('.case').removeAttr('checked');
});

//should be able to complete the fill by function based off the above

//to get the selected, you weren't far off, biggest thing should actually be
//the setting of value instead of id.
var selected = [];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() { 
    selected.push($(this).val());
});
//spit the array out so you can see what you end up with.
console.log(selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are storing `undefined` values in an array as your checkboxes do no have `value` attributes, also your markup is invalid, `input` element  doesn't have closing `</input>` tag, supposing your inputs have following classes, you can use `map` method and store the values in an array.

```
var selected = $('#table tr').has('input[type=checkbox]').map(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       return {
          val: $this.find('input[type=checkbox]').val(),
          email: $this.find('input[type=text].email').val(),              
          name: $this.find('input[type=text].name').val(),
          // ...
       }
})
```